# Very slow this cypher query, is there any optimization?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using **Neo4J 2.1.5**.

Data:

2000 persons
Goal:  For each person, calculate the total of friends, friends' friends, friends' friends' friends.
Result is like follows:
Person FullName | Friends total | Friends-2 total | Friends-3 total | global total

```
MATCH (person:Person)
WITH person
OPTIONAL MATCH person-[:KNOWS]-(p2:Person)
WITH person, count(p2) as f1
OPTIONAL MATCH path = shortestPath(person-[:KNOWS*..2]-(f2:Person))
WHERE length(path) = 2
WITH count(nodes(path)[-1]) AS f2, person, f1
OPTIONAL MATCH path = shortestPath(person-[:KNOWS*..3]-(f3:Person))
WHERE length(path) = 3
WITH count(nodes(path)[-1]) AS f3, person, f2, f1
RETURN person._firstName + " " + person._lastName, f1, f2, f3, f1+f2+f3 AS total
```

The tricks is to avoid wrong calculations with cylic graph; that's why I use `shortestPath`.

However, this query lasts long: 60 seconds! 
Any optimization possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]

Does this work for you?

```
MATCH (person:Person)
OPTIONAL MATCH (person)-[:KNOWS]-(p1:Person)
WITH person, COALESCE(COLLECT(p1),[]) AS p1s 
WITH person, CASE p1s WHEN [] THEN [NULL] ELSE p1s END AS p1s
UNWIND p1s AS p1
OPTIONAL MATCH (p1)-[:KNOWS]-(p2:Person)
WHERE NOT ((p2 = person) OR (p2 IN p1s))
WITH person, p1s, COALESCE(COLLECT(DISTINCT p2),[]) AS p2s
WITH person, p1s, CASE p2s WHEN [] THEN [NULL] ELSE p2s END AS p2s UNWIND p2s AS p2
OPTIONAL MATCH (p2)-[:KNOWS]-(p3:Person)
WHERE NOT ((p3 = person) OR (p3 IN p1s) OR (p3 IN p2s))
WITH person,
  CASE p1s WHEN [NULL] THEN 0 ELSE SIZE(p1s) END AS f1,
  CASE p2s WHEN [NULL] THEN 0 ELSE SIZE(p2s) END AS f2,
  COUNT(DISTINCT p3) AS f3
RETURN person.firstName + " " + person.lastName, f1, f2, f3, f1+f2+f3 AS total;
```

Each friend is only counted once.

Here is an explanation of some of the more obscure tactics used. The query has to to replace empty `p1s` and `p2s` collections with `[NULL]` so that `UNWIND` will not abort the rest of the query. Then, when counting the size of the collections, we need give `[NULL]` collections a count of `0`.

Comment: f1 is right but it does not return good results for f2 and f3.
I expect 51 for f2 but it returns 73.

Comment: Adding a `distinct` : `COLLECT(distinct p2)` helps but it is still 53 instead of 51.

Comment: Are you sure that the extra 2 people are not valid? Replace the last `WITH` and the current `RETURN` clause with `RETURN *`. That will show you all the collections.

Comment: I have added the `DISTINCT` to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Actually it returns 49 instead of 51. There is some restriction that my query in the OP doesn't have...

Comment: I have also changed `COUNT(p3)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT p3)`. Also, instead of using `RETURN *`, as stated in a prior comment, it might be better to use `RETURN p1s, p2s, COLLECT(DISTINCT p3) AS p3s`.

Comment: I understand what went wrong ;)  It's a real detail. Nice job for this query, I will use it ;)